# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source tpe "Task<List<Stocks>> StockList" select not found

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I tried to improve my desktop application by Adding Async/Await querying a database here is my code

```
public async Task<List<Stocks>> StockListAsync()
    {
        List<Stocks> stocks = new List<Stocks>();
        {
            conn = await App_Code.DbConnection.InitializeConnectionAsync();               
            string cnt = "SELECT * FROM tblStock";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cnt, conn);               
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (await rd.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var rm = new Stocks
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["ID"]),
                        Supplier = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Supplier"]),
                        StockCode = rd["StockCode"].ToString(),
                        StockName = rd["StockName"].ToString(),
                        Description = rd["Description"].ToString(),
                        UnitMeasure = rd["Measurement"].ToString(),
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Quantity"]),
                        OrderQty = Convert.ToInt32(rd["OrderQty"]),
                        Cost = Convert.ToDouble(rd["Cost"]),
                    };
                    stocks.Add(rm);
                }
            }
            return stocks;
        }



        //}
    }
```

This code above is a separate class called Stocks then I the windows form I want to display the result I have created an instance of the stock class like this *** readonly Stocks stock = new Stocks();*** and I also have a method **GetStock** below is the code

```
 void GetStocks()
    {
        var list = stock.StockListAsync();           
            var result = from g in list 
                         select g;
            GrdFood.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                GrdFood.Rows.Add(GrdFood.RowCount + 1, item.Supplier, item.StockName,
                    item.Description, item.Quantity.ToString("N2"), item.OrderQty.ToString("N2"),
                    Convert.ToDouble(item.Cost).ToString("N2"), item.ID);

            } 
    }
```

Then on the FormLoad event I called **GetStocks** The problem is that the **List** in the code below  is reporting an error *Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type Task> StockList select not found*

```
 var list = stock.StockListAsync();           
            var result = from g in list 
                         select g;
```

Everything was working fine before I made it Async Task, please how do I correct this implementation thanks.

Comment: urge to check out [async programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to async and await the call stock.StockListAsync.
Something like this

```
async void GetStocks()
{
    var list = await stock.StockListAsync();           
        var result = from g in list 
                     select g;
        GrdFood.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            GrdFood.Rows.Add(GrdFood.RowCount + 1, item.Supplier, item.StockName,
                item.Description, item.Quantity.ToString("N2"), item.OrderQty.ToString("N2"),
                Convert.ToDouble(item.Cost).ToString("N2"), item.ID);

        } 
}
```

`StockListAsync()` is returning `Task<List<Stocks>>` not `List<Stocks>` to apply query hence the error.

Comment: `async void` is not recommended.   If you must use await, then you have to use `async Task`, and you will find you need to use it everywhere.

Comment: @Neil yes it is not a good practice. But solution proposed is addressing specific concern of the post. Also i commented the post to check out async programming basics which give him more insight on that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't using async/await properly, the type of `list` is `Task<List<Stock>>`, not `List<Stock>` because that's how async works

```
Task<List<Stock>>list = stock.StockListAsync();
```

What you actually want is:

```
List<Stock>> list = await stock.StockListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But, to use `await`, your function must be `async`:

```
async Task GetStocksAsync() <-- Async functions should have an Async suffix
{
    var list = await stock.StockListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var result = from g in list 
                     select g;
        GrdFood.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            GrdFood.Rows.Add(GrdFood.RowCount + 1, item.Supplier, item.StockName,
                item.Description, item.Quantity.ToString("N2"), item.OrderQty.ToString("N2"),
                Convert.ToDouble(item.Cost).ToString("N2"), item.ID);

        } 
}
```

Then your problem is that you need to change your code that calls GetStocksAsync to also be async/await etc etc.  At this point you are probably wondering if it's all really worth the effort to rewrite something that already works to be async.

Comment: Thanks guys your answers are great, I was actually reading an article to learn the async then I decided to try it on my existing application, just to be clear @Nell what does **.ConfigureAwait(false);** mean? Am not sure what that is.